# IAM permissions issues with S3KeySensor

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-iam, mwaa

I'm trying to use an `S3KeySensor` in my MWAA.

```py
    sensor = S3KeySensor(
        task_id="wait-for-my-file",
        bucket_key="my-file.txt",
        bucket_name="my-bucket",
    )
```

I keep getting this error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

I have added relevant permissions to the AWS Airflow execution role in terraform (and checked that the change were effective in the aws console):

```
  statement {
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["s3:HeadObject"]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
      "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
    ]
  }
```

For the benefit of the doubt I've also added `GetAccountPublicAccessBlock`, as mentioned in the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/mwaa-create-role.html):

```
  statement {
    effect    = "Allow"
    actions   = ["s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock"]
    resources = ["*"]
  }
```

Am I missing something? Should I use a custom `aws_conn_id`?

Comment: So you have defined  `s3:GetObject` and `s3:ListBucket` somewhere in your code?

Comment: I don't but I didn't think it was needed given the error is for `s3:HeadObject`

Comment: I don't see such a permission here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html.

Comment: oh, my bad. I've mixed up actions like `HeadObject` with permission like `GetObject`. So I guess the question is what is the minimum permission I need to the sensor to be able to check that the file exists (using `HeadObject`) ?

Comment: Hard to tell, would you be able to add the entire data source for the policy?

Comment: The S3KeySensor is just calling boto3 under the hood. You can look at the classes [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/main/airflow/providers/amazon/aws). It looks like you need ListBucket for running the S3.Client.head_bucket - this is just a quick glance. It might be worth you exploring those in more details to see how you can get more precise.